# Calculate maximum and minimum value for each raster from rasterBrick

Tags: r, raster

I want maximum and minimum values in the form of raster form a raster stack using a loop. But when I apply my code I got the value only for single raster. How do I  get it for different layers from rasterBrick?

```
    tem <- tem # the rasterBrick with 12 different layers 
    max_t <- for (i in 1:nlayers(tem)) {
    e <- calc(tem[[i]], function(x){min(x, na.rm = T)})

   }
```

returns the value for just single layer with

> "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)"

Comment: Did you look at the warnings()?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use a loop? Also the `min` of a single layer just returns that layer. I would do this

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
x <- range(b, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Or

```
z <- calc(b, range, na.rm=TRUE)
```

You can also do

```
xn <- min(b, na.rm=TRUE)
xx <- max(b, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Rather then reporting there are warnings you should inspect them, and perhaps report the message. But here, they surely are complaining about

```
min(NA, na.rm=T)
#[1] Inf
#Warning message:
#In min(NA, na.rm = T) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Comment: Thank you. In fact, my concern is not about warning I just mentioned it how it was there. I want to use loop because I have around 60 raster files doing manually would take more time. So searching for more automated way of doing it.

Comment: My point is that in R you typically do not use loops -- it is more work to use a loop. And in would seem that in this case it makes no sense.